# Given a subgroup $H$ and a normal subgroup $N$, does the normal closure of $H$ in $HN$ intersect $N$ in the normal closure of $H \cap N$ in $N$?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group, $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$, and $H$ be any other subgroup of $G$.    Write $\mathrm{ncl}_G(H)$ for the normal closure of $H$ in $G$.

Is it true that $\mathrm{ncl}_{NH}(H) \cap N = \mathrm{ncl}_{N}(H \cap N)$?

Evidently $\mathrm{ncl}_{NH}(H) \cap N \supseteq \mathrm{ncl}_{N}(H \cap N)$, but the reverse inclusion seems unlikely.  Still, none of the counterexamples I've tried to construct have quite panned out.

Comment: You mean the normal closure of $H \cap N$ in $N$, not in $H$, since $H \cap N$ is clearly already normal in $H$.

Comment: Exactly right!  Thanks for flagging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. In order for this to be false, $G$ would have to be non-abelian. So let $G=S_3$. Let $N$ be generated by $(1,2,3)$ and $H$ by $(1,2)$. Then $HN=G$, and the normal closure of $H$ in $HN$ is $G$. This clearly intersects $N$ in $N$. But $H\cap N=1$. So the normal closure of $H\cap N$ in anything is $1$.

Comment: Wonderful!  This is perfect, thank you!!!  (don't have enough points to up-vote, but would if I could!).

Comment: You can accept the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it, @Greg.

Comment: Ah, great.  Thanks!